# React boilerplate with ssr, react-router 4, hot reloading, eslint, css modules, code splitting

Tags: reactjs

React.js looking very simple and understandable if you work with a simple app. But it becomes a huge butthurt if you trying to use together: server-side rendering with react-router 4, hot reloading, eslint, dev-server, css modules, webpack2, code splitting etc. And there's no any good and useble boilerplate with all these stuff.  I spent so many time to find something suitable. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question is not really suitable for StackOverflow as it is too broad. It might be worth checking out [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle).

Comment: It doesn't work, many errors during the setup